# How to register the app in google cast console

Tags: api, console, google-cast

I am new to the casting technique.I want to learn and  use the casting technique in my same app but when i try to register in Google cast developer console its asking for a money to register. Is there  any alternate option to use casting with free registration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Default Media Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default).  You don't need to register your app.

Comment: In the link they also mentioned as default app_id where we will  get the default app_id

Comment: For iOS platform, it is kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID.   https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloVideo-ios/tree/master/HelloVideoGoogleCast

Comment: Default Receiver ID's are listed here: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default